# Setting up Liquibase with MS-SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, liquibase, legacy, legacy-database

I am utilising Liquibase (www.liquibase.org) into our MVC3 SQL Server 2008 project to manage database migration/changes. However I'm stumbling on the first hurdle: Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server instance.

I am looking at the quick start tutorial on the liquibase site, but exchanging the mysql for sql server DB

I run this command:

```
liquibase --driver=sqljdbc.jar  --changeLogFile="C:\Temp\ChangeLog.xml"  --url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=test"  --username=user --password=pass   migrate
```

And receive this error:

```
Liquibase Update Failed: Cannot find database driver: sqljdbc.jar
```

I have tried adding --classpath pointing to the sqljdbc driver with no luck.

How can I create or update an MS-SQL Server database with liquibase?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a properties file called **liquibase.properties** containing the following:

```
classpath=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\\sqljdbc_1.2\\enu\\sqljdbc.jar
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test
username=myuser
password=mypass
changeLogFile=C:\\Temp\\ChangeLog.xml
```

liquibase will use this file when located in the same directory. Useful to simplify the command-line.

Database is updated as follows:

```
liquibase update
```

Notes:

- I'm not a SQL server user, I picked up the JDBC driver and URL details from [Microsoft doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- The "migrate" command has been deprecated.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot Mark. Used the newer mssql jdbc 3.0 driver and added double backslash to locations e.g C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft......

Comment: Thanks very much for your help... But I keep asking myself... how they don´t put this kind of info on docs page?

Comment: Its not advisable to use absolute path for the parameter ```changeLogFile=C:\\Temp\\ChangeLog.xml``` because the absolute path will differ from programmer to programmer as he/she chosen.
.  Liquibase uses the change set ID, author and filename to create a check sum to validate if a change has already been processed.  (http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/why-does-the-change-log-contain-the-file-name).

So, it's better to include directory name in ```classpath``` parameter as suggested by @nvoxlandas in the forum mentioned.

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti I fully accept your point. The answer is 3 years old, dating back to a time when I was chained to a windows workstation... there I found that explicitly stating the full directory pathname worked more reliably in Java....

Fortunately this is all a dim and distant memory :-)  Thank you for your comment