# Liquibase maven plugin is not using classpath property

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

For some reason the Liquibase maven plugin is not using my property when I set it in my `liquibase.properties` file. When I run `mvn liquibase:update` I get the following INFO.

```
[INFO] there are no resolved artifacts for the Maven project.
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: target/classes/liquibase.properties
[INFO]   'classpath' in properties file is not being used by this task.
```

Due to this, the update fails as liquibase can't find the driver and can't connect to the database.

I saw this SO question but they are using the liquibase executable and not maven. I used it as an example on how to use the liquibase.properties file.

[Setting up Liquibase with MS-SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990467/setting-up-liquibase-with-ms-sql-server)

I see where it is hitting an exception L571 to L588 the exception but the actual exception isn't printed out so I don't know the cause of the error.

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/9ae7f90a0bbbbcec229a0788afa74831db348ced/liquibase-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/liquibase/maven/plugins/AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java#L573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than setting the classpath in a properties file, you must put the driver jar as a dependency in your maven POM.

See the [documentation for the Liquibase Maven Task](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/), and especially the section that describes different JDBC dependencies. Here's a snippet:

> Example of Maven Liquibase Update
>
> You need to ensure that you include the relevant JDBC driver for your
>   database in the dependency section of Maven POM file.
>
> MySQL example:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <!-- Replace with the version of the MySQL driver you want to use -->
            <version>${mysql-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Yup! This seems to fix the issue. I added the MSSQL driver to my POM file dependency and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a simple copy and paste issue.

The property `driver` in `liquibase.properties` ends with a space. after deleting the space everything was fine.

`driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

vs

`driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265057/2820586) put me in the right direction. In my case, it was that I needed to declare the Maven resource.

```
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Hope it helps!